# Redirect with Dynamic Parameters in URL

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, url, redirect

I do not know how to format this question to be clear enough, so please bear with me. I will do my best.

Lets say I want to redirect one url to another, i.e:

```
www.site1.com ==> www.site2.com
```

Now, let's say the first url has parameters `name` and `email` so it looks like:

```
www.site1.com/?name=SOMETHING&email=SOMETHING
```

and the values under name and email are dynamic ones.

Is there a way to make a script which will automatically know how to redirect this:

```
www.site1.com/?name=SOMETHING&email=SOMETHING ==> www.site2.com/?name=SOMETHING&email=SOMETHING
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following rule in site1/.htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} name=.+&email=.+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://site2.com/ [L,R]
```

This will redirect http://site1.com/?name=something&email=something to http://site2.com/?name=something&email=something

Comment: Does this redirect entire website? since my site1.com looks like this: site1.com/something/

Comment: Yes ,it redirects any uri that contains **name** and **email** querystring perameters.

Comment: How can I make it to takes parameters after the /something/ folder?